# Determing when a stored procedure was last compiled

Tags: sybase, plan-cache, sybase-ase

Is there a way to find when a procedure last had an execution plan compiled in Sybase ASE 16?

I don't see a "modified" datetime column in sysobjects, and I haven't been able to find a Sybase equivalent to a queryable plan cache to see if that has a date.

Comment: ASE does not have a 'alter procedure' command so what do you mean when you say 'altering the procs (with no changes)'?  when you say (re)compile are you talking about 'sp_recompile'? 'exec ... with recompile'? or are you talking about dropping/recreating the proc?

Comment: @markp My mistake, it was `replace procedure`, not `alter procedure`. I was not directly involved with the process, and it turns out that the initial solution was to simply run most of the procs manually once (instead of through the ETL program), and that got the ETL off the ground. One of those procs got missed, and after updating the proc to add some troubleshooting (via `replace`), it started working in the ETL program.. I've removed that portion from my question, since it's unhelpful, and just adds clutter.

Comment: for *compiled* times of procs currently residing in proc cache, see `master..monCachedProcedures.CompileDate`

Comment: @markp Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you put that in an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compile times of procs currently residing in proc cache, see `master..monCachedProcedures.CompileDate`